# make a pop up navigation menu

Tags: html, css, web

I've got a pretty easy one but I just can't seem to get it.  I am a student in a basic HTML and CSS class and I've got an assignment due tomorrow but I can't get my navigation up to spec.

It is supposed to look and pop up like this:

http://ista230.com/images/assignments/7/page1.jpg

http://ista230.com/images/assignments/7/page2.jpg

Right now I am just trying to get the divs to pop up but I am getting stuck.  At first I was using an ul for my nav links but I saw some other examples using divs.  So thats where I am at.

Heres the HTML for the nav:

```
<nav id="nav">
       <a href="#"><div class="navItem">Home</div></a>
       <a href="#"><div class="navItem">Upcoming Flights</div></a>
       <a href="#"><div class="navItem">About Us</div></a>
       <a href="#"><div class="navItem">Travel Guide</div></a>
       <a href="#"><div class="navItem">Contact Us!</div></a>
</nav>
```

And here is what I have so far for CSS:

```
/* Navigation */
nav{
    margin-left:5%;
    margin-right:5%;
    margin-bottom:5%;
    margin-top:10%;
    width:100%;
}

#nav a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}

div.navItem
{

    list-style:none;
    padding:2% 4%;
    display:inline;
    background-color:orange;
    border:5px solid #597CBB;
    border-radius:10px;
}
.navItem div{

    -moz-transition: height 1s ease; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: height 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: height 1s ease; /* Opera */
    -ms-transition: height 1s ease; /* IE9 (maybe) */
    transition:height 1s ease;

}

.navItem:hover div
{
    height:500px;
}
```

Comment: Your css says `.navItem:hover div`, but "navItem" is the class of the div itself, which doesn't have a child div.  I don't want to do your assignment for you, so I'll just say that you need the `:hover` selector to be on something else.  Also, I think using a list would be good for you here.  It's a list of links.

Comment: So something like div.navItem:hover  ?

Comment: And instead `display: inline`, try switching that to `display: inline-block`

Comment: Ok, last question.  Doing that worked but the divs extend downward.  I tried using a negative height but that broke it.  Any ideas?

Comment: Sure, I thought this would come up next! Look at the images you posted, you can see there's a big gap above the menu, ready for the items to go up into.  So, consider setting a `height` or `min-height` on the `<nav>`, or giving it some padding at the top.  Then you just need to work out how to _position_ (hint) the menu items at the bottom of the `<nav>`

Comment: So I am getting the items to extend vertically now by increasing the top-padding.  However, it pushes the rest of my content down.  I've tried some different positioning combinations in the nav and my other areas of content but its not really solving the problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40926/discussion-between-greg-and-davidpauljunior)

Answer (score 0):

Like *davidpauljunior* said, you need to change `.navItem:hover div` to `div.navItem:hover`, because you are not modifying a div inside class `navItem` - you are modifying the div itself with the class `navItem`.

You also need to change the display of class navItem to `display:inline-block` so you are able to set the div's height. You cannot set the height of a `display:inline` element.

Here are the changes you need to make to the css:

```
/* Navigation */
nav{
    margin-left:5%;
    margin-right:5%;
    margin-bottom:5%;
    margin-top:10%;
    width:100%;
}

#nav a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}

div.navItem
{

    list-style:none;
    padding:2% 4%;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:orange;
    border:5px solid #597CBB;
    border-radius:10px;
    -moz-transition: height 1s ease; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: height 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: height 1s ease; /* Opera */
    -ms-transition: height 1s ease; /* IE9 (maybe) */
    transition:height 1s ease;

}

div.navItem:hover{
    height:500px;
}
```